# Bitcoin price speculation resources

Tags: exchange-rate, speculation, community

Where could I discuss Bitcoin price speculation, and calculating fair spot and future price.

In general for stackexchange sites, the factors for here and now would be "too localized" I think.

So I will try to broaden it. Bitcoin price - being a deflationary currency with a known max number of coins that haven't been mined or minted yet - seems to be functioning like futures converging to a spot price.

The variable factors being perceived difficulty in mining versus advances in hardware to allow mining, if you look at the difficulty charts and their correlation to price, so far.

I think with just these two factors it will be possible to calculate theoretical prices, independent of the buy/sell bidder's market.

Does anyone have any resources on this, or perhaps a better place to discuss this

Comment: I'm not sure that an question which requires a list of sites is best for this format. There's not really a definitive answer.

Comment: @ColinDean there are plenty of answers across stack exchange sites that do this. Some are even protected by Community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Speculation board on the BitcoinTalk forum is nonstop speculation.  That would probably be the best place to share your theories and analysis and to collaborate. [Enjoy!](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=57.0).

There is a fair amount of discussion that falls under the category of speculation that also occurs on the [#bitcoin-otc IRC channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#bitcoin-otc).

And [/r/bitcoin](http://reddit.com/r/bitcoin) on Reddit seems to get its share of "OMG $30 Soon!" posts.